# Perlbrew perl installation failure ../lib/h2ph.t

Tags: perl, ubuntu, perlbrew

I have perl 5.22 (Ubuntu 16.04). One software I am using has some issues and needs older perl (older than 5.22). I tried installing 5.20.1 with  perlbrew but I got the error:

```
makefile:840: recipe for target 'test_harness' failed
```

with mention of file:
    ../lib/h2ph.t
I tried using --force, and patch as suggested after failure.

Does the older perl no longer being maintained imply anything in this case?

Does anyone have any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: Seems to be a problem with some versions of 5.20: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1126500 (I've installed versions all the way back to 5.6.1 without issue using perlbrew)

Comment: Yeah, thanks that worked.

Comment: Can you please write an answer showing what exactly you did?